# Create instance of class with member of Type T, without specifying T type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class of this structure:

```
public class ClassName<T>
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<T> ObjectList { get; set; }
}
```

A collection of `ClassName` is situated in `ParentClass`

```
public ParentClass
{
    public List<ClassName<T>> Property {Get;set;}
    //Other properties...
}
```

To create an instance of this class, I would do the following:

```
var item = new ClassName<string>();
```

Is it possible to create an instance of this class without specifying the type of `T` ?

I have tried

```
var item = new ClassName<null>();
var item = new ClassName();
```

But obviously these do not work....

Comment: Try with nullable type ? like new ClassName<int?>(null);

Comment: I guess the standard iffy way of doing this would be to use `object`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you just want to accept arguments of any type, use new ClassName<object>().  But that's pretty unhealthy.

Comment: If your type has a generic argument you certainly have to provide it. What is the benefit of a generic argument when *not* providing it? Why you need this? mAybe you want a non-generic base-class from which your generic one derives?

Comment: Because not all instances of the class require this variable - almost all will ignore it and I do not see the point in randomly assigning a type to it

Comment: does that mean that not all instances need the `ObjectList` ?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes, that is correct

Comment: If the bulk of items don't use the `List<T>` why don't you make that generic part of the interface a subclass specialization? You'll end up with `class ClassName` and `class SpecializedClassName<T>:ClassName`

Comment: Then you should consider to make an extra type which inherits from a base class.

Comment: If not all `ClassName`-instances need an `ObjectList`, the latter shoudln´t be part of that class, but of a derived class.

Comment: @MongZhu I have already done that, the problem is that the class is a child of another class and I cannot assign the inheried class to the parent

Comment: please provide this very important information in your post, then we can see how to solve this **new** situation

Comment: @MongZhu I have now updated the question, but as a note,  I was not asking for help in solving this problem, I just wanted to know the answer to the question I asked

Comment: _"I just wanted to know the answer to the question I asked"_  a simplistic answer is that if you don't provide `T`, the compiler cannot ascertain the underlying type of `ObjectList`

Comment: "the problem is that the class is a child of another class" I don't see any inherital relationships. `List<ClassName<T>> Property` is just a property. `ClassName` does not inherit from any other classes

Comment: @MongZhu apologies, my language was incorrect - I meant the class is a property of another class - my words were incorrect, but my illustration above is how my code is

Comment: @Alex that is fine. To treat this case, actually my solution should work. I made an edit to incorporate this case. Have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an instance of this class without specifying the type of T ?

In short: NO.

concerning your comment as why you want to do that:

> Because not all instances of the class require this variable

the I would suggest to subdivide the classes.

```
public class ClassNameBase
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class ClassName<T> : ClassNameBase
{
    public List<T> ObjectList { get; set; }
}
```

This way you create object that need the list with a specific type. Due to inheritance they will have all other properties also that the base class provides.

EDIT:

If you want to mix the different cases of objects with and without the `ObjectList` you can create a collection of the base type:

```
public ParentClass
{
    public List<ClassNameBase> Property {Get;set;}
    //Other properties...
}
```

now all the different brothers will fit nicely into the same list `Property`.

If you want to access the `ObjectList` in one of the elements you need to cast them:

```
ClassName<int> temp = Property[0] as ClassName<int>;

if(temp != null)
{
    temp.ObjectList.Where(....
}
```

Comment: I have tried this implementation, but cannot see how to access the properties of the inherited class eg ParentClass.Property.ObjectList

Comment: @Alex either you need to cast them : `(ParentClass.Property[0] as ClassName<int>).ObjectList` Here you should check for null if the element does not have the ObjectList and cannot be casted

Comment: @Alex or you could implement a method that does a certain action and override it in the child class

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because if you don't precise the type T, how .NET know to init the type of the objects in your list.

But FYI, you can do a simple inherit, for example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var c = new MyClass();
    var d = new MyClass<long>();
}

class MyClass<T>
{
    public List<T> ObjectList { get; set; }
}

class MyClass: MyClass<int>
{
}
```

With this code above, when you write `new MyClass();`, it inits your list with type `int` by default.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better not to include the generics and `List<T>` in the base class at all?

Comment: agree with @spender it should be designed like the answer from Mong Zhu